# Wait- Expected conditions not working for auto-suggestion within Yahoo Finance page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, autosuggest

Below code is not able to identify the list of webelements if they are identified inside a wait condition. I get an exception as timeoutexception and unable to identify the element for the specified xpath.

However if I directly access the elements without wait condition , the values are assigned to the list Variable, why is this so?

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.finance.yahoo.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='yfin-usr-qry']")).sendKeys("nclh");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
List<WebElement>dd_list= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='modules_list__1zFHY']/li")));
System.out.println(dd_list.size());

for(WebElement ele : dd_list) {

    if (ele.getText().contains("NCLH.VI")) {
        System.out.println("i got the element");
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do finally ?

Answer (score 1):

> why is this so?

The elements that you are targeting are never *all* visible simultaneously. Your xpath returns 15 elements, of which only 10 are visible. Implying that your condition will never be met (hence the timeout exception). Simply refine your xpath so as to target the elements you are interested in: the ones that have vocation to be visible, e.g. `"//ul[@class='modules_list__1zFHY']/li[@data-type='quotes']"`

[image]

Comment: if i directly print the values without wait, then it gets assigned to the List variable, which means they are loaded right?

Comment: @my3rddimension Right!

Comment: so that means , there is nothing wrong with the xpath, why is it failing when i put inside a wait condition

Comment: @my3rddimension See my edit. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: Thank you, i got it now.. thanks so much for your response and time.. really helped me to understand explicit wait conditions better

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/) website contains [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled elements. So you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for `document.readyState` to be **`complete`** and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.finance.yahoo.com");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='yfin-usr-qry']")));
  element.click();
  element.sendKeys("nclh");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='modules_list__1zFHY']//li[@data-type='quotes']"))).size())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  6
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: YahooFinance]